# Inject a service in Startup.cs in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working on a .NET Core 3.1 application. I have a requirement where i have to inject a service in Startup.cs. My code is:

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices(servicesCollection =>
                {
                    servicesCollection.AddScoped<IUnauthorizedAccessService, UnauthorizedAccessService>();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IUnauthorizedAccessService unauthorizedAccessService)
{
        Configuration = configuration;
        _unauthorizedAccessService = unauthorizedAccessService;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public IUnauthorizedAccessService _unauthorizedAccessService { get; set; }
```

When i run the code, i get the following exception:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Interface.Service.IUnauthorizedAccessService' while attempting to activate 'Website.Startup'.'
```

How can i inject the service in Startup.cs ? I have even tried it getting in `Configure` method. But then, i get the exception at repository level. Code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IUnauthorizedAccessService unauthorizedAccessService)
        {
            _unauthorizedAccessService = unauthorizedAccessService;

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=User}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

I have a method `RegisterDatabase` which is being called from `ConfigureServices`. Code:

```
private void RegisterDatabase(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<TrainingContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }
```

Service code is:

```
public class UnauthorizedAccessService : IUnauthorizedAccessService
    {
        private readonly IEventLogRepository _eventLogRepository;
        public UnauthorizedAccessService(IEventLogRepository eventLogRepository)
        {
            _eventLogRepository = eventLogRepository;
        }

        public async Task<BaseResponse> LogUnauthorizedAccessInDB(string user, string url, string sessionId)
        {
            try
            {
                EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
                eventLog.Httpsession = sessionId;
                eventLog.AppUserName = user;
                eventLog.EventDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                eventLog.MessageLevel = 3;
                eventLog.Message = url;

                await _eventLogRepository.Add(eventLog);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return HelperService.Response(null, null);
        }
    }
```

When Adding the object, i get the exception

```
Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'TrainingContext'.
```

All of my other repositories are working but, getting exception only at this point. What can be the possible issue ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Basically, what i am trying to achieve is that i want to log unauthorized access to my site in Database. Code is:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(o =>
                {
                    o.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error";
                    o.LoginPath = "/Login";
                    o.SlidingExpiration = false;
                    o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                    {
                        //OnRedirectToAccessDenied = new Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task>(context =>

                        OnRedirectToAccessDenied = new Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task>(test)
                    };
                });
```

test method is:

```
private async Task<Task> test (RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            string user = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            string url = "/" + context.Request.Host.Value + "/" + context.Request.RouteValues["controller"] + "/" + context.Request.RouteValues["action"];
            string sessionId = context.HttpContext.Session.Id;

            await _unauthorizedAccessService.LogUnauthorizedAccessInDB(user, url, sessionId);

            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
            return context.Response.CompleteAsync();
        }
```

Comment: The pipeline hasn't been built at that point. You could get access to it in the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app...)` method in `Startup.cs` by calling `app.ApplicationServices.GetService<...> ();` But, why would you need it in to `Startup.cs` at all?

Comment: @Andy got your point. I have updated the question, can you kindly look into it

Comment: I still don't understand why you need `IUnauthorizedAccessService` in your `Startup.cs` -- this could be an XY Problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Andy, "Cannot resolve scoped service 'Interface.Service.IUnauthorizedAccessService' from root provider.'" getting this exception now

Comment: Yeah -- because what you are doing is unorthodox. This isn't how any of this works. There are zero reasons you should need access to that *scoped* service in your startup.cs. Until you explain that, you will get nowhere.

Comment: I want to log unauthorized access to my site in DataBase. I am trying to assign a callback to "OnRedirectToAccessDenied" property. Thats why i need access to a service instance in startup.cs

Comment: i don't see `OnRedirectToAccessDenied` code anywhere in your question.

Comment: @Andy question updated

Comment: I put an answer up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a scoped object that implements `CookieAuthenticationEvents`. For example:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApplication.Services
{
    public class MyCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        private readonly IUnauthorizedAccessService _unauthorizedAccessService;

        public MyCookieAuthenticationEvents(
            IUnauthorizedAccessService unauthorizedAccessService)
        {
            _unauthorizedAccessService = unauthorizedAccessService;
        }

        public override Task RedirectToAccessDenied(
            RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            // TODO: you can use _unauthorizedAccessService here
            return base.RedirectToAccessDenied(context);
        }
    }
}
```

To inject this, you'd do it as so:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.EventsType = typeof(MyCookieAuthenticationEvents);
    });

services.AddScoped<MyCookieAuthenticationEvents>();
services.AddScoped<IUnauthorizedAccessService, UnauthorizedAccessService>();
```

Make sure you remove that `IUnauthorizedAccessService` from your `program.cs`. You don't inject there. You inject in your `Configure` method.

This is how you do proper dependency injection. You don't do what the accepted answer is doing. That is probably one of the most unorthodox things I have ever seen in a long time.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andy. It worked for me like a charm :). This code resolved all the issues related to Scoped, Singleton object of service and repository. Your help is much appreciated. Once again thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

`Startup.cs` is designed for configuring own services and pipeline configuration. You can not inject your custom services in constructor just because they are not configured yet.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0#code-try-1):

> The host provides services that are available to the Startup class
> constructor. The app adds additional services via ConfigureServices.
> Both the host and app services are available in **Configure** and
> throughout the app.